React Native Prevent child re-render
I tried a bunch of different variations of useCallback and useMemo, as well as React.memo, but it doesn't have the behavior I want, can anyone help me?  The problem is that whenever the state of the parent is changed (like when I turn the phone side ways, or when "isShown" changes) it re-renders the child and re-triggers the read-data function which not only waste data because it causes another call to the backEnd, but the user also has to wait for the data to be fetched again.  Is there a way to not re-trigger handleReadData of the child each time the parent is re-rendered?
parent :
export default function Parent({}) {

const [isShown, setIsShown] = React.useState(false);

{...}

const WifiModuleSection = ({title, wifiModule, wifiSection}) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.sectionWifiModuleContainer}>
          <View>
            {...}
          </View>
          <WifiModuleControls wifiModule={wifiModule} t={t} i18n={i18n} />
        </View>
    );
  };

return return (
                    <View>
                      {WifiModules.map(wifiModule => {
                       return (
                        <View style={{display:isShown ? 'flex' : 'none'}}>
                         <WifiModuleSection
                          title={wifiModule.name}
                          wifiModule={wifiModule}
                          wifiSection={wifiSection}
                         />
                        </View>
                       );
                      })}
                      {...}
                    </View>
                );
}


child :
const WifiModuleControls = ({wifiModule, t, i18n}) => {

{...}

const handleReadData = async () => {
    //Request Read state-data
    try {
      setLoadingReadData(true);
      const formData = {...};
      const res = await client.post('/read-data', formData);

      if (res.data.success) {
        {...}
        setData(res.data.data);
        setLoadingReadData(false);
      } else {
        Toast.showShortBottom('Error: ' + res.data.message);
        setLoadingReadData(false);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Toast.showShortBottom('Error : ' + error);
      setLoadingReadData(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
      handleReadData();
  }, []);

if (loadingReadData) {
    return (
      <ActivityIndicator
        style={{marginBottom: 1}}
        color={currentMainThemeColor}
        size={60}
      />
    );
  }

 return (
    <View>
    {...}
    </View>
 );
};

export default WifiModuleControls;

I simplified code to only show relevent parts

This isn't about preventing re-renders. It's either about:

Preventing "unmounting/remounting" OR
Caching data OR
Lifting state up (similar to 2, but not the exact same)

The problem is WifiModuleControls owns the fetching of data and the holding of it in state so that when it unmounts, that data is then "lost" and the only way to get it back is to refetch it when your component mounts again.
This happens because of this line:
                      {isShown &&
                        WifiModules.map(wifiModule => {
                          return (
                            <WifiModuleSection
                              title={wifiModule.name}
                              wifiModule={wifiModule}
                              wifiSection={wifiSection}
                            />
                          );
                        })}

If isShown is false, then the components unmount and the data is gone. When isShown is true again, the components mount again and the only way to get their data back to refetch it all again.
You can do several things to resolve your issue:

Always keep the component mounted, just maybe make it invisible
Move the fetching and state to the parent component and pass the fetched data into the WifiModuleSection. This way, when WifiModuleSection unmounts, the data is still held in the parent component.
Cache the fetched data - this is where libraries like useSWR or tanstack-query shine brightest.

EDIT:
Option 1: I'm relatively naive to react-native, but if you wanted to keep everything else the same, instead of conditionally rendering based on isShown, the below would probably work:
{WifiModules.map(wifiModule => {
    return (
      <View style={{display:isShown ? 'flex' : 'none'}}>
        <WifiModuleSection
          title={wifiModule.name}
          wifiModule={wifiModule}
          wifiSection={wifiSection}
        />
      </View>
    );
})}

This means that you'll have to get rid of the conditional rendering using isShown - so the whole snippet looks like this:
{isShown && // remove this line entirely
    WifiModules.map(wifiModule => {
      return (
        <View style={{display:isShown ? 'flex' : 'none'}}> // replace with this conditional
            <WifiModuleSection
              title={wifiModule.name}
              wifiModule={wifiModule}
              wifiSection={wifiSection}
            />
        </View>
      );
    })}


great explanation! thx for quick response! how Can I implement option 1?

@Phil see my edit

thx!  let me test that, I'll get back to you in a few minutes

Alright I changed it, it doesn't work out of the blue with just that modification, there is something else I need to add I guess?

You'll have to define "doesn't work" - what specifically doesn't work? Also, what does your complete code look like now?

I replaced the part you said was causing problem with the code provided in your edit, for now it has the same behavior as before, meaning it still re-fetches the data on each parent re-render

@Phil - you're still doing conditional rendering (unmounting the compoennt each time isShown is set to false). My goal is not to give you copy-pastable snippets, but to educate you as to the underlying problem and the potential solutions you have available to you. See my second edit for clarification. The solution is that 1. the component's can't unmount OR 2. the data needs to be fetched/maintained somewhere outside the components whose lifecycle changes. That's it. Once you understand those two concepts, there's a ton of ways you can resolve your issue that are specific to your code base.

I did remove "isShown &&" and replaced it with : <View style={{display:isShown ? 'flex' : 'none'}}> 3 lines below

@Phil - then something is unmounting/remounting the component above it. Maybe it's because of a table that only mounts the component on scroll. If that's the case, you'll have to check, but your WifiModule component is being unmounted. Exactly why, I don't know, that's specific to your codebase. It sounds like it's time to investigate fetching and storing your wifi data outside of your component. This is where I'd recommend useSWR or tanstack query, although you can do it easily enough with redux (or something like redux). tl;dr - don't tie your data to your components lifecycle (in this case)

alright thx I'll try to investigate further why the component is being unmounted

I fixed it by using a context provider, I'll mark your answer as the solution since you gave a good explanation

Great way to fix it, happy you got it resolved @Phil!
